# What does the '{' symbol (curly-brace) indicate in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm currently learning Java, and was given a question that seems to defy a simple answer:

> What is the meaning of the following symbol in Java: `{`?

Of course, there are the common meanings: the body of an `if` statement, `for` loop, other control structures. But then it could also be the start of a method, or an initializer - these seem to have less in common.

I've spent a good bit of time searching for a single definition for this symbol in the context of Java, but haven't found anything that would suffice here.

**What is an all-encompassing definition of what the opening curly brace indicates in Java?**

Comment: **Moderator note**: I've locked this question to stop the tug-of-war where two factions appear to be fighting over this post by closing/deleting / and undeleting/reopening the post repeatedly. If either side cares this much, please post a question on [Meta] to find a consensus on the faith of this question.

Comment: Meta discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339881

Comment: I've edited this in an attempt to focus it; [new meta discussion can be found here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340229/can-the-meaning-of-the-curly-brace-in-java-be-expressed-in-a-few-paragraphs).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question from your instructor seems not so great because there isn't a single unified meaning of the { symbol in Java.

In the context of a statement, the { symbol is used to denote the start of a block statement. This accounts for all the uses of { with if statements, while loops, for loops, do ... while loops, switch statements, etc., which technically only apply to a single statement but are often used with block statements:

```
if (x == 0) {
    statementOne();
    statementTwo();
}
```

In the context of a method or type (class/interface/enum/annotation), the { symbol is used to denote the beginning of the body of a class or a method:

```
public class NewClass {
    ...

    public void foo() {
         ...
    }
}
```

It can also be used inside a class to declare an initializer or static initializer block:

```
class MyClass() {
    static int x;
    static {
        x = somethingHorrible();
    }
};
```

In the context of an array literal, the { symbol is used to denote the beginning of the list of elements used inside that literal:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 3, 7};
```

Each of these uses of the open brace symbol is different from all the others. In fact, the language would work just fine if we used a different symbol for each of these different contexts.

I think that the best answer to your question is that { is used in contexts where some group of things will be treated as a unit, whether it's a block statement (many statements treated as a single one), a class (many methods and fields treated as a single object), a method (many statements treated as a single unified piece of code), an initializer (many things that need to be done at once), etc.

In the majority of these contexts, as the comments have pointed out, the brace introduces a new scope. Statement blocks, class bodies, initializer bodies, and function bodies all introduce a new scope, and that is definitely something important to keep in mind. (Array initialization doesn't do this, though.)

Comment: Though I think you wrote a good answer I disagree about the question being "not so great". One of the big obstacles of young programmers is to understand the meaning of *scope*. In all the examples you provided there is one mutual connection and it is the "beginning of a new scope".  The [scope](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html) is the *context* that you mention in the answer.

Comment: @alfasin That's true for most of the examples, but it doesn't hold for array literal initialization. I do see what you're saying, though.

Comment: @alfasin Actually, the more I think about it, the more I agree with you. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> What is an all-encompassing definition of what the opening curly brace indicates in Java?

There isn't one. The closest thing I can give you is something vague like:

- *"The start of some sort of sequence of language constructs, terminated by a closing curly brace."*

The reason that there is no more precise *single* definition to be given is that an opening brace is part of several different language constructs, including at least (perhaps I missed some):

- [Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)
- [Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)
- [Class Bodies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBody)

Significantly, note that *not* every construct in Java that involves some stuff enclosed in braces is a "block". The specification, linked above, defines a "block" as a sequence, enclosed by braces, of zero or more `BlockStatement`s. It further defines a `BlockStatement` as being either a [local variable declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-LocalVariableDeclarationStatement), a [class declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassDeclaration), or a [statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement). While this definition covers a lot of Java constructs that use braces - for instance, a [static initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) is a block, and the body of a `for` or `if` statement, if enclosed in braces, is a block - it does *not* cover class bodies or array initializers, which have different content to blocks.

The lack of a single, all-encompassing definition of `{` should not be surprising or in any way philosophically unsatisfactory. Imagine the following analogous question:

> What is an all-encompassing definition of what word "of" indicates in English?

There is, of course, no such all-encompassing definition; rather, "of" is a word of [many meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of). The best you can do is either to say "'of' is a preposition" or to enumerate the individual meanings, like a dictionary does.

Comment: You missed Annotations - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1

Comment: While I don't 100% agree with you, where we differ is more matter of opinion than fact. Your answer is more coherent than mine and "The start of some sort of sequence of language..." is more or less in line with what I wanted to say (even though I would call it a block), so +1

Answer (score 1):

In Java when you open a curly brace it means that you open a new *scope* (usually it's a nested scope). One important thing to understand is that a variable that you'll define inside this scope (which end where you put the closing curly brace) will not be recognized outside of the scope.

The other way is not true: if you define a variable outside the scope and then open a new one, the variable will be recognized from inside the nested scope.

Example:

```
int k = 5;
if (true) { //opening a new scope 
    // k is recognized here!
    int i = 10;
}
// here i is not recognized
```

Curly braces are mandatory in some cases, such as:

- class declaration
- method declaration

and sometimes it's optional, for example:

- following an `if`, `while` and `for` statements

There are many other cases in which curly braces are used: nested classes, anonymous classes, initializers, static initializers and more. In each case we use the same syntax (curly braces) but it carries different semantics.

Comment: If the downvoters and the delete voters would care to comment... maybe this answer could be improved... :)