# why does my IntelliJ IDEA show a Fatal error whenever i run it?

Tags: java

Here  is My code

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pTPB.png)

/*
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\????????????????????.IdeaIC2019.3\system\compile-server\codewithsujit_25647921\timestamps\data
java.io.IOException: Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\????????????????????.IdeaIC2019.3\system\compile-server\codewithsujit_25647921\timestamps\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:175)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.(PersistentHashMap.java:149)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.(PersistentHashMap.java:138)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.(PersistentHashMap.java:129)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.(PersistentHashMap.java:121)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.(PersistentHashMap.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.JpsPersistentHashMap.(JpsPersistentHashMap.java:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.(AbstractStateStorage.java:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.FileTimestampStorage.(FileTimestampStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectStamps.(ProjectStamps.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.(ProjectTimestamps.java:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)*/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace. A curly brace tells java where a class, method, or statement starts and stops.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

You can read more about [curly braces here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-are-curly-braces-in-java/).
Intellij also tells you that you are missing a curly brace as seen here
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GeAU.jpg) .
[Here is some more information to help you understand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229317/what-does-the-symbol-curly-brace-indicate-in-java)